# How I can discover, what means all bytes in binary representation of float-pointing type?

Tags: c++

How I can discover, what means all bits in binary representation of float-pointing type?
If I have a double, or float, or long double, every type take some bytes. For example, double in Visual C++ takes 64 bits, 1 for sign, 11 for exponent and 52 for mantissa. But in other processor or compiler this numbers are change. Are there some constant numbers (like EPS), with his help I can discover how many bytes in current system using for sign, exponent and mantissa, in float, double and long double???

Comment: This could be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point Note that C++ does not fix the size of `float`, `double` etc.

Comment: [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) mentions "usually IEEE-754" for `float` and `double`, and "does not necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754" for  `long double`. So check your compiler documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) template from `<limits>` gives various constants that might be useful:

- [`radix`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/radix) to indicate whether the representation is binary, decimal or something else;
- [`digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) for the number of mantissa bits (assuming a binary radix)
- [`min_exponent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min_exponent) and [`max_exponent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_exponent) from which the range (and hence number of bits) of the the exponent can be calculated.

There will only be one sign bit in any sane representation.

Comment: +1 did not know it went to that degree of granularity. I need to get out more.

Comment: There's also a trait function to check if the representation conforms to IEEE-754 I believe.

Comment: Is there any way before c++11?

Comment: @SidZhang: I'm fairly sure all of these traits were in C++98. There are also similar constants in the C library header `<climits>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: There's `is_iec559` to check whether the type conforms to the standard, but that covers more than just the representation.